# Fast way of multiplying two 1-D arrays

Tags: hardware, vhdl, verilog, fpga, asic

I have the following data:

```
A = [a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 .... a24]
B = [b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 .... b24]
```

which I then want to multiply as follows:

```
C = A * B' = [a0b0 a1b1 a2b2 ... a24b24]
```

This clearly involves 25 multiplies.

However, in my scenario, only 5 new values are shifted into A per "loop iteration" (and 5 old values are shifted out of A). Is there any fast way to exploit the fact that data is shifting through A rather than being completely new? Ideally I want to minimize the number of multiplication operations (at a cost of perhaps more additions/subtractions/accumulations).  I initially thought a systolic array might help, but it doesn't (I think!?)

Update 1: Note B is fixed for long periods, but can be reprogrammed.

Update 2: the shifting of A is like the following: a[24] <= a[19], a[23] <= a[18]... a[1] <= new01,  a[0] <= new00. And so on so forth each clock cycle

Many thanks!

Comment: Does `B` stay the same through the whole process of shifting?

Comment: How about building 5 multipliers to work in parallel or 1 multiplier clocked at 5x rate?

Comment: What is B like? e.g. if this was a DSP algorithm with fixed filter length, B could consist of small coefficients with an average of less than 2 bits set.

Comment: What's with the tags? Is this C code or vhdl or assembly or something entirely else? What are you trying to do? Design a CPU or write a program to execute on one?

Comment: @jalf :-) its dedicated hardware, I'm just trying to increase the number of eyeballs that see this question - there are not that many subscribers to the vhdl or verilog tags

Comment: @dasblinkenlight B stays the same .... most of the time, but can be reprogrammed.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen The values of B are currently about 16 bits - these possibly could be optimized

Comment: I'd consider in that case distributed arithmetic with CSA tree.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I only want a single clock here. 5 multipliers in parallel?  I'm not sure how that would work? I need 25 results per clock cycle and 5 new values are shifting in per clock cycle

Comment: by **shifting** do you mean that the element at that index is being replaced by a new one? for example `a[0]` with new element or `a[0]` with `a[1]`and `a[1]` with `a[2]` an so on?are you playing with DMA for direct storage?

Comment: @Koushik the new values a[25] <= a[20], a[24] <= a[19]... a[1] <= new01,  a[0] <= new00. I hope this clarifies matters

Comment: it should be 26 multiplications rite as per your code?

Comment: Sorry, zero index description bug there! Its 25 multiplications, entries are from 0 to 24 - I'll update the question

Comment: @trican: "trying to incrase the number of eyeballs"... by inserting misleading tags? Here, have a downvote. Next time, try using *relevant* tags.

Comment: @jalf - I disagree strongly, I believe those are suitable tags - this is an algorithmic question regarding efficient implementation (albeit in hardware) - if there is an optimization possible people knowledgeable on low c or assembly are as likely to be able to contribute useful suggestions (see andand's answer below) as hardware orientated folk. Alternatively what tags would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any fast way to exploit the fact that data is shifting through A rather than being completely new?

Even though all you're doing is the shifting and adding new elements to A, the products in C will, in general, all be different since one of the operands will generally change after each iteration.  If you have additional information about the way the elements of A or B are structured, you could potentially use that structure to reduce the number of multiplications.  Barring any such structural considerations, you will have to compute all 25 products each loop.

> Ideally I want to minimize the number of multiplication operations (at a cost of perhaps more additions/subtractions/accumulations).

In theory, you can reduce the number of multiplications to 0 by shifting and adding the array elements to simulate multiplication.  In practice, this will be slower than a hardware multiplication so you're better off just using any available hardware-based multiplication unless there's some additional, relevant constraint you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

on the **very first 5** data set you could be saving upto 50 multiplications. but after that its a flat road of multiplications. since for every set after the first 5 set you need to multiply with the new set of data.

i'l assume all the arrays are initialized to zero.
i dont think those 50 saved are of any use considering the amount of multiplication on the whole.

But still i will give you a hint on how to save those 50 maybe you could find an extension to it?

1st data set arrived : multiply the first data set in `a` with each of the data set in `b`. save **all** in `a`, copy only `a[0]` to `a[4]` to `c`. **25 multiplications here**.

2nd data set arrived : multiply only `a[0]` to `a[4]`(having new data) with `b[0]` to `b[4]` resp. save in `a[0]` to `a[4]`,copy to `a[0->9]` to `c`. **5 multiplications here**

3rd data set arrived : multiply `a[0]` to `a[9]` with `b[0]` to `b[9]` this time and copy to corresponding `a[0->14]` to `c`.**10 multiplications here**

4th data set : multiply `a[0]` to `a[14]` with corresponding `b` copy corresponding `a[0->19]` to  `c`. **15 multiplications here**.

5th data set : mutiply `a[0]` to `a[19]` with corresponding `b` copy corresponding `a[0->24]` to  `c`. **20 multiplications here**.

total saved mutiplications : **50** multiplications.

6th data set : usual data multiplications. **25 each**. this is because for each set in the array `a` there a new data set avaiable so multiplication is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add another array D to flag the changed/unchanged value in A. Each time you check this array to decide whether to do new multiplications or not.